# specific childrow hierarchy for radgridview

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I would like to iterate through the rows on my RadGridView when data binding is complete and for each row modify the columns which are shown on one of its child templates (one hierarchy level beneath).
I've tried this:

```
void rgvQuestions_DataBindingComplete(object sender, GridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        bool didit = false;
        foreach (var row in rgvQuestions.Rows)
        {
            if (!didit)
                row.ViewInfo.ViewTemplate.ChildGridViewTemplates[1].Columns[0].IsVisible = false;

            didit = true;
        }
    }
```

But it hides the column for all of the child gridview templates and not not only for the specific row (first row in this case).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each Row has a ChildRows collection where its child rows are stored:

```
 foreach (var row in radGridView1.Rows)
 {
     foreach (var childrow in row.ChildRows)
     {
         //do smth
     }
 }
```